# How do I ignore transparent pixels when using Numpy to calculate the mean of an image?

Tags: python, numpy, transparency, mean, alpha-transparency

How do I ignore transparent pixels when using Numpy to calculate the mean of an image?

The packages I've imported:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as spi
from skimage import io,transform,img_as_float
from skimage.io import imread,imsave
```

The image is loaded:

```
target_img = spi.imread(target_img, mode="RGB").astype(float)/256
```

I then get the image's mean and subtract it from the image:

```
mu_t = target_img.mean(0).mean(0)
t = target_img - mu_t
```

The variable `target_img` will have some fully transparent pixel of which I want both steps to ignore when calculating `mu_t` and `t`.

If there is no way to ignore transparent pixels, then would adding a fake color values, like `257` would instead for what I want to do?

Then as a follow up question, how can I make sure that the transparent pixels will not affect these lines of code:

```
from numpy import eye 
t = t.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,-1)
Ct = t.dot(t.T) / t.shape[1] + eps * eye(t.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

> numpy.nanmean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=)[source]
>   Compute the arithmetic mean along the specified axis, ignoring NaNs.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html

So now all you have to is turn your transparent pixels into NaN.

If you want the mean of the whole picture, rather than along an axis, you could also flatten the array to one dimension, remove all the transparent pixels, and then take the mean.

Comment: So instead of using transparency as a way to determine which pixels I should ignore, NANs will easier? Like using: `target_img.nanmean(0).nanmean(0)`?

Comment: What about ignoring any NANs in `target_img`, when I run: `t = target_img - mu_t`?